# How to get Twitter Bootstrap.js Table Pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Well , I may sound basic for some here,but this requirement of mine is really pulling me down ,my requirement is I want to have a table with pagination in twitter-bootstrap.js .Say like

[image: Table with pagination]

I could design the table, but could not bind pagination with the table,should I add some external css and js files?or am I trying something which isn't feasible ?

Please help me .
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful YUI3 [http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/] api It also have facilities for pagination,sorting,exporting etc with the table data . ;) .